# How to select a feature from kmz file using ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, geojson, ogr2ogr, kmz, layer-to-kml

Below is the sample data I have succesfully able to import geometry of this into db, but I want **Detection time** field to be imported as well.

```
    "features": [{
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
                "Name": " Fire Detection Centroid ",
                "description": " \n            \n                <b>Latitude: <\/b> 40.39129<br\/> \n                <b>Longitude: <\/b> -79.85131<br\/> \n                <b>**Detection Time: <\/b> 2022-08-09 03:20 **UTC<br\/> \n                <b>Sensor: <\/b> Terra MODIS<br\/>\n                <b>Confidence [0-100%]: <\/b> 95%<br\/> \n                <b>Day\/Night: <\/b> Night<br\/>\n                <b>Scan: <\/b> 1.1 km<br\/>\n                <b>Track: <\/b> 1.1 km<br\/>\n                <b>FRP: <\/b> 5.1 MW<br\/>\n                <b>Brightness: <\/b> 304.97 K\n            \n        "
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [-79.85131, 40.39129]
            }
        }
```

This is ogr2ogr script I used:

```
ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" 'PG:host=xyz user=abc dbname=1234 password=pass' ${filename} -sql "select *,OGR_STYLE from \"${element}\"" -append -nln $name -skipfailures;
```

What changes I need to in above command to load Detectime Time into db?

Comment: that's GeoJson not KML (or KMZ) -

Comment: You can't without writing a script to parse the HTML in the description. Suggest you download the shapefile instead.

Comment: @IanTurton Hi I apologies forgot to mention file was kml then I converted to geojson to make it readable.